# light box bg flicker issue before pre loader comes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create light box with prelaoder..Although i have done this but the only problem i came across is light box background(mask) flicks before to come the prelaoder. It happens only first time when we click refresh/open the page.

Here is working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/4nQk5/2/

Script:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
        function customOverlay(){ 

                var popupWin = $("#custom-popup-win");
                var popMargTop = ($(popupWin).height()) / 2; 
                var popMargLeft = ($(popupWin).width()) / 2; 

                $(popupWin).css({ 
                    'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
                    'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
                });

                $('#preloader').delay(3500).fadeOut('slow')

                $(".popup-window").click(function(){
                    $("#custom-overlay").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#custom-popup-win").fadeIn("slow");
                }); 

                $("#custom-popup-win .close-button").click(function(){
                    $("#custom-overlay").fadeOut("fast");
                    $("#custom-popup-win").fadeOut("fast");
                }); 


        }

        customOverlay();

});

</script>
```

Styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
body { font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; }
#custom-overlay { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; /*background:url(images/bg-repeat.png) 0 0;*/ z-index: 1000; display: none;
opacity: 0.6;
filter: alpha(opacity=60);
 }
#custom-popup-win { width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; background: #fff; position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; z-index: 1500; box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; /*-o-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000; -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;*/ display: none; }
#custom-popup-win table { margin: 20px; }
#custom-popup-win table td { width: 20%; padding: 5px 12px; }
#custom-popup-win .close-button { cursor: pointer; /*padding:5px 3px;
    background:#000;
    color:#ccc;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    box-shadow:0 0 20px #777;*/
position: absolute; width: 26px; height: 26px; top: -10px; right: -10px; background-image: url(images/popup_close_btn.png); }
#preloader { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background-color: #fff; z-index: 99; }
#status { width: 200px; height: 200px; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; background-image: url(images/status.gif); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; margin: -100px 0 0 -100px; }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Popup" class="popup-window"  />
<div id="custom-overlay"></div>
<div id="custom-popup-win">
        <div class="close-button"></div>
        <div id="preloader">
                <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <table width="90%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                        <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                        <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                        <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                        <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                        <td>lorem ipsum</td>
                </tr>

        </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work

Comment: @Danko..link is updated and working ..http://jsfiddle.net/4nQk5/2/

Comment: You want the loading be always or only the first time? ... http://jsfiddle.net/4nQk5/37/

Comment: i want loading first time, and it is coming first time, the issue is when we refresh the page and first time click on popup button than for one second popup background comes & disappear and than preloader comes.. i dont want that lightbox's background comes before the prelaoder.

Comment: Did you see the fiddle i post?